# PHPStan error: Method should return specific types but returns mixed

Tags: php, phpdoc, phpstan

I'm using PHPStan for static analysis in my PHP 8.4.2 project, and I'm encountering an issue with a class method that returns multiple types or null. Here's my method with type hints and PHPDoc comment:

```
   /**
    * Returns a value of the requirements array by its key
     * @return array<string, mixed>|string|int|float|null
     */
    public static function getRequirementsArrayImageByKey(string|int $key): string|int|float|array|null
    {
        return self::$requirementsArrayImage[$key] ?? null;
    }
```

The method returns either an array with string keys and mixed values, a string, an int, a float, or null. I believe my type hints and PHPDoc comment should be correct.

However, PHPStan gives me the following error:

***[phpstan] Method Core\DataManager::getRequirementsArrayImageByKey() should return array<string, mixed>|float|int|string|null but returns mixed.***

I tried adding explicit type checks as a workaround, but I'm not satisfied with this solution, as it adds unnecessary complexity to the code. I'm looking for a cleaner solution to address this issue.

What am I missing, or how can I configure PHPStan to understand the correct return types without adding extra type checks in my code?

**Addendum:**
$requirementsArrayImage looks like this:

```
    /**
     * Provides basic requirements
     * @var array<string, array<string, string|int>|string|int|float>
     */
    private static array $requirementsArrayImage = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$requirementsArrayImage = [
            'allowed_ratio' => ['1', '4/3', '16/9'],
            'allowed_file_types_array' => ['jpeg', 'png'],
            'min_pixels' => 2000,
            'min_width_px' => 400,
            'min_height_px' => 200,
           ...
        ];
    }
...
```

Comment: I think the error message is saying that it can't deduce the type of `self::$requirementsArrayImage[$key]`. What is the declaration and docblock for the static property `$requirementsArrayImage`?

Comment: see above please...

Comment: I don't know if it's the cause, but that initialisation doesn't seem to match the declared type: `['1', '4/3', '16/9']` and `['jpeg', 'png']` are of type `array<int, string>`, or more simply `string[]` - they will be assigned integer keys; that doesn't match `array<string, string|int>` which you've declared for the property, or `array<string, mixed>` which you've declared for the method, both of which require *string* keys.

Comment: It'd be best to reproduce the problem on phpstan.org/try. And ask in PHPStan's GitHub Discussions, you're more likely to get a fast and correct response there :)

Answer (score 0):

Your array declarations aren't compatible with the arrays assigned to them. To work with the array you pass in the constructor, you need to change the code to:

```php
    /**
     * Provides basic requirements
     * @var array<string, array<string|int, string>|string|int|float>
     */
    private static array $requirementsArrayImage = [];

    /**
     * Returns a value of the requirements array by its key
     * @return array<string|int, string>|string|int|float|null
     */
    public static function getRequirementsArrayImageByKey(string|int $key): string|int|float|array|null
    {
        return self::$requirementsArrayImage[$key] ?? null;
    }
```